# Filtering with criteria conditioned on the first criteria in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

I would like to filter rows based on two criteria:

(1) the row is marked "include" in some indicator column, and

(2) the row falls within a one minute period after a column which is to be included by the first criteria.

I can solve this using standard filtering methods within a loop, but is there a more sophisticated solution? I would love to see what people can come up with.

Here is a toy data set and the desired result based on the description of the problem:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
time = c(0, 0.46, 0.73, 1.25, 1.58, 2.23, 2.65, 3.18, 3.45, 3.73, 4.26, 4.6, 4.66, 5.25, 5.78, 5.89, 6.51, 6.71, 6.97, 7, 7.95, 8.52, 8.93, 9.19, 9.28, 10.15, 10.75, 11.67, 11.88),
ind = c('include', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'include', 'include', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'include', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'include', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude'))

df_des <- tibble(
time = c(0, 0.46, 0.73, 2.23, 2.65, 3.18, 3.45, 5.78, 5.89, 6.51, 6.71, 10.15, 10.75),
ind = c('include', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'include', 'include', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'include', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'exclude', 'include', 'exclude'))
```

Here is my current solution:

```r
df_tst <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  row_i <- slice(df, i)
  if(row_i$ind == "exclude"){
    next
  }else{
    df_tst[[i]] <- filter(df, time >= row_i$time, time <= row_i$time + 1)
  }
}
df_tst <- bind_rows(df_tst) %>%
  distinct(., time, ind) %>%
  arrange(., time)
```

where `df_tst` yields the same answer as the desired result in `df_des`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution, that splits the data into groups at each occurrence of `"include"`, and then filters within those groups:

```
df %>%
    # Associate each row with the most recent "include"
    mutate(group = cumsum(ind == "include")) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    filter(time <= (first(time) + 1))
```

Output (`group` column left in to demonstrate how it works but can be dropped):

```
# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   group [5]
    time ind     group
   <dbl> <chr>   <int>
 1  0    include     1
 2  0.46 exclude     1
 3  0.73 exclude     1
 4  2.23 include     2
 5  2.65 include     3
 6  3.18 exclude     3
 7  3.45 exclude     3
 8  5.78 include     4
 9  5.89 exclude     4
10  6.51 exclude     4
11  6.71 exclude     4
12 10.2  include     5
13 10.8  exclude     5
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for @Marius. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In the *data.table* package, this could be achieved with a rolling join:

```
setDT(df)
df[ind=="include","time"][df, on="time", roll=+1, nomatch=0L]
#     time     ind
# 1:  0.00 include
# 2:  0.46 exclude
# 3:  0.73 exclude
# 4:  2.23 include
# 5:  2.65 include
# 6:  3.18 exclude
# 7:  3.45 exclude
# 8:  5.78 include
# 9:  5.89 exclude
#10:  6.51 exclude
#11:  6.71 exclude
#12: 10.15 include
#13: 10.75 exclude
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using base R `Map`. First we find out indices where `ind = "include"` and get all the rows between the corresponding `time` value and a minute after that.

```
include_ind <- which(df$ind == "include")
df[unique(unlist(Map(function(x, y) which(df$time >= x & df$time <= y),
                 df$time[include_ind], df$time[include_ind] + 1))), ]

# A tibble: 13 x 2
#    time ind    
#   <dbl> <chr>  
# 1  0    include
# 2  0.46 exclude
# 3  0.73 exclude
# 4  2.23 include
# 5  2.65 include
# 6  3.18 exclude
# 7  3.45 exclude
# 8  5.78 include
# 9  5.89 exclude
#10  6.51 exclude
#11  6.71 exclude
#12 10.2  include
#13 10.8  exclude
```

Comment: @thelatemail yes, there were some overlaps. I have corrected it now. Thanks :)